# How to store raw JSON in Couchdb with java

Tags: java, json, couchdb

I am currently parsing a web service that give me Json Documents as response. I want to store those in CouchDb using java, but I cannot find a way. With the couchdb library for java (Ektorp, couchdb4j etc...) I can only store java documents in the database, which would mean I have to transform my raw json to java Document in order to store them. 
Do you have any idea how i could directly store raw json ?
Many thanks in advance

Comment: I guess the question is a little confusing, so maybe that is why it got down voted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ektop documentation provides [an example](https://web.archive.org/web/20161214002713/http://ektorp.org:80/reference_documentation.html#d100e610) of updating a document using JSON stored in a file:

```java
 File file = someMethodToGetFile();
 InputStream jsonInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
 db.update("document_id",
           jsonInputStream,
           file.length(),
           null);
```

Instead of using the `FileInputStream`, if your JSON is in memory in your java program (e.g. as a String), you could wrap the string in a `ByteArrayInputSteam`:

```java
 String yourJsonString = ...

 InputStream jsonInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(yourJsonString.getBytes());
 db.update("document_id",
           jsonInputStream,
           file.length(),
           null);
```

Alternatively, CouchDB is accessed through a restful API so you can interact with CouchDB using any java library that understands REST, for example using [Apache HttpClient](https://hc.apache.org/httpclient-legacy/):

```java
String yourJsonString = ...

StringRequestEntity requestEntity = new StringRequestEntity(
    yourJsonString,
    "application/json",
    "UTF-8");

PostMethod postMethod = new PostMethod("http://couchdb.server/database");
postMethod.setRequestEntity(requestEntity);

int statusCode = httpClient.executeMethod(postMethod);
```