# post android JSON object into couchdb database

Tags: android, json, http, couchdb

I've created an database with iris couch and now I want to save some data of input fields in there.

First of all I've built a JSON object with all the wanted data in it:

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.newnode_layout, container,false);

    nodeName = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.nodeName);
    nodeAddress = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.nodeAddress);
    nodeCity = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.nodeCity);
    nodeComment = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.nodeComment);



    /*//////////////// SAVE NODE BUTTON ////////////////*/
    saveBtn = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.saveBtn);

    saveBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            inputName = nodeName.getText().toString();
            inputAddress = nodeAddress.getText().toString();
            inputCity = nodeCity.getText().toString();
            inputComment = nodeComment.getText().toString();

            JSONObject jsonDoc = new JSONObject();
            try {
                jsonDoc.put("name", inputName);
                jsonDoc.put("latitude", pLat);
                jsonDoc.put("longitude", pLong);
                jsonDoc.put("address", inputAddress);
                jsonDoc.put("city", inputCity);
                jsonDoc.put("comment", inputComment);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } // end try
            body = jsonDoc.toString();
        }
    });
```

I'm a newbie on this topic. I've still searched in the couchdb wiki how to post an JSON object into the database but I cannot really make head nor tail of it.

I would be thankful for every hint you can give me.
Thanks!

Comment: Have a look [at this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28277090/1033422) this should do what you want if you are happy to use the [ektorp](http://ektorp.org) library.